# How do i call a function inside a key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been learning Javascript since the start of this year so I don't know very much.

`a.click(function(){a.setup()}),{key:"setup", value:function(){ /code/ }}`

I want to call the function(?) "setup" but I don't know how. Is there a way do to it?

Comment: maybe you have a look to [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functions inside objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378341/functions-inside-objects)

Comment: @Leo I don't think this question is a duplicate of the other one. Granted, I am not even sure what this one is asking but it seems OP already knows how to have functions inside objects. What I don't understand where `setup` is and how OP wants to invoke it.

Comment: @vlaz I think it is explained in the other question, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @Leo it does not explain my question, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

its not quite clear what your object looks like because usually you dont have "key" and "value" explicitly mentioned. if you literally have a function assigned to a key called "setup", you could do:

```
var myobject = { setup: function() { console.log('foobar') } };
// call the function:
myobject.setup(); // "foobar"
```

and else, you already know `value`:

```
myobject.value();
```