# Function inside an object (ApexChart)

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

In my object in ApexChart I have 2 values that I want to change dynamically. This works well:

```
min: 1675123200000,
max: 1675206000000,
```

My code to change (just console log test for now) is this:

```
min: {
                myfunc(min) {
                    min = 1675123200000;
                    console.log('MIN', min);
                    return min;
                }
            },
```

I believe is nothing wrong with my code but I wonder if I missing something. (I am of the view that my question is not a duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378341/functions-inside-objects)).

There is no error and no console.log result. Looks like the value is just missing and the entire script is ignoring it.

Could be because my code is wrong or perhaps the script (ApexChart) do not accept the function there?

Comment: I don't have any view on the duplicate nature of that other question, but in general it can sometimes help if you can explain (in the question itself) why another question does not solve your problem. That will help the reader explain how the other question does help, or indeed if they agree, they can submit an answer.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't look like valid JS. You're missing a property name inside the `min` object, and the `function` keyword before your function declaration. (Have a look at the "Pre ES6 style" section of the [top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48645842/1650337))

Comment: Thank @DBS I tried both ES6/PreES6. I don't understand what you said about the property name inside min

Comment: Basically: `{ function a(){} }` isn't valid, it would need to be `{ name: function a(){} }` (Where `name` is whatever the relevant property name is)

Comment: I understood. I did this too but nothing changed: `min: function min(val) {
                var val = 1675123200000
                    min = val;
                    console.log('MIN', min);
                    return min;
            }`